# Axios error still thrown to console with Tanstack Query onError

Tags: error-handling, axios, react-query

Using Tanstack Query, I have this mutation set up:

```
export const useMuteMutation = () => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  console.log(authStore.accessToken);

  const muteRequest = (muteData: any) => {
    return axiosClient.post("/muted-users/", muteData);
  };

  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ["mute_player"],
    mutationFn: muteRequest,
    onSuccess: (resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    },
    onError: (error: any) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    },
  });
};
```

Now, when i getting 401 or 500 or any error for that matter being returned by the post request, I am able to long the message to the console, but **also** the entire AxiosError is being thrown in the console? How do I prevent this without going the try-catch route?

Comment: Then what error do you expect?